# python scraping exchange rate data

Tags: python, python-2.7

An application that a friend uses depends on daily exchange rate figures from a particular site [link to source of rates](http://bog.gov.gh/data/bankindrate.php)

The problem is there is no set time when the rate is changed which is affecting business since sometimes when the rate is changed she might be out and so until he comes back any transaction that happens will use the last rate entered. Sometimes she wins other times she looses out. I'm trying to create an automated client that will scrape and update the exchange rate for her independently.

So far I have been able to strip the content of the site down to a list:

```
[
<td style="text-align: left;">U.S Dollar</td>,
<td>USDGHS</td>, <td>1.8673</td>, <td>1.8994</td>,
<td style="text-align: left;">Pound Sterling</td>,
<td>GBPGHS</td>, <td>3.0081</td>, <td>3.0599</td>,
<td style="text-align: left;">Swiss Franc</td>,
<td>CHFGHS</td>, <td>2.0034</td>, <td>2.0375</td>,
<td style="text-align: left;">Australian Dollar</td>,
<td>AUDGHS</td>, <td>1.9667</td>, <td>2.0009</td>,
<td style="text-align: left;">Canadian Dollar</td>,
<td>CADGHS</td>, <td>1.8936</td>, <td>1.9259</td>,
<td style="text-align: left;">Danish Kroner</td>,
<td>DKKGHS</td>, <td>0.3255</td>, <td>0.3311</td>,
<td style="text-align: left;">Japanese Yen</td>,
<td>JPYGHS</td>, <td>0.0226</td>, <td>0.0230</td>,
<td style="text-align: left;">New Zealand Dollar</td>,
<td>NZDGHS</td>, <td>1.5690</td>, <td>1.5964</td>,
<td style="text-align: left;">Norwegian Kroner</td>,
<td>NOKGHS</td>, <td>0.3307</td>, <td>0.3363</td>]
```

I'm now strugling a bit to create a dictionary like so

```
{USDGHS: [1.8673, 1.8994], GBPGHS: [3.0081, 3.0599], ...}
```

I'll then use the dictionary to update the appropriate table in the database.

I got to this stage by using beautifulsoup4 and urllib2

[Edit]

Code that got me to this point

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = "http://bog.gov.gh/data/bankindrate.php"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

td = soup.find_all('td')

another_soup = BeautifulSoup(td[:-3])

print another_soup
```

Comment: It looks like you just need to use beautifulsoup4 a little further... could you post the code that's got you this far? It'll help someone if they want to experiment

Comment: @JonClements Is on the money here (no pun intended).  You should be building a DOM out of the response you get from the source and then traversing that to pull out the data your interested in.  It looks like right now, you are doing text parsing instead, which usually makes your life harder in these sorts of situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first find the rows (`tr` tags) and use those to then get the columns (`td` tags):

```
currencies = {}
trs = soup.find_all('tr') # find rows
for tr in trs[1:-3]: # skip first and last 3 (or whatever)
    text = list(tr.strings) # content of all text stuff in tr (works in this case)
    # [u'U.S Dollar', u'USDGHS', u'1.8673', u'1.8994']
    currencies[text[1]] = [float(text[2]), float(text[3])]
```

And put those into a dictionary using the appropriate key with a value of the two numbers converted to floats...

```
>>> currencies
{u'USDGHS': [1.8673, 1.8994], u'JPYGHS': [0.0226, 0.023], u'CHFGHS': [2.0034, 2.0375], u'CADGHS': [1.8936, 1.9259], ...}
```